# Use of @Retry and @Transactional on REST endpoints

Tags: quarkus

To handle serialization errors from PostgreSQL I'm using the `@Retry` annotation on my API endpoints (according to the official documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html).

Those endpoints also have a `@Transactional` annotation of course.

However, if I get the `could not serialize access due to concurrent update` error during the commit phase, no retry is happening. It's properly retrying if the error is raised before.

Am I missing something?

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
2021-05-12 12:30:25,568 WARN  [com.arj.ats.arjuna] (executor-thread-20) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff0a2aa683:a38d:609baa5c:4cb, org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization@1ad95da4 >: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.wrapLockException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:277)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1366)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:360)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1295)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.CDIDelegatingTransactionManager.commit(CDIDelegatingTransactionManager.java:97)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.endTransaction(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:313)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:160)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:100)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:53)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.zig:340)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at com.example.resource.TowerResource_Subclass.ascend(TowerResource_Subclass.zig:417)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:643)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:507)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:457)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:459)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:419)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:393)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:68)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter.doFilter(ResteasyFilter.java:35)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:63)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:65)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:111)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:108)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:587)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:152)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$1.handleRequest(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:119)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:290)
        at io.undertow.server.DefaultExchangeHandler.handle(DefaultExchangeHandler.java:18)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$5.handle(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:408)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$5.handle(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:381)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1038)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:137)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$4.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:338)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$4.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:316)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1038)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:137)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:132)
        at io.undertow.websockets.vertx.VertxWebSocketHandler.handle(VertxWebSocketHandler.java:116)
        at io.undertow.websockets.vertx.VertxWebSocketHandler.handle(VertxWebSocketHandler.java:51)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1038)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:137)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer.doPermissionCheck(HttpAuthorizer.java:116)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer.access$100(HttpAuthorizer.java:27)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer$2.accept(HttpAuthorizer.java:133)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer$2.accept(HttpAuthorizer.java:122)
        at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.UniCallbackSubscriber.onItem(UniCallbackSubscriber.java:69)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.access$100(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:26)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:50)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:90)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer.doPermissionCheck(HttpAuthorizer.java:122)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer.checkPermission(HttpAuthorizer.java:99)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$3.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:218)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$3.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:210)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1038)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:137)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$2$2.onItem(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:143)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$2$2.onItem(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:104)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniMemoizeOp.drain(UniMemoizeOp.java:152)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniMemoizeOp.onItem(UniMemoizeOp.java:172)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.DefaultUniEmitter.complete(DefaultUniEmitter.java:36)
        at io.quarkus.security.runtime.QuarkusIdentityProviderManagerImpl$1$1$1$1.run(QuarkusIdentityProviderManagerImpl.java:58)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3492)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3354)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3768)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)
        ... 122 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
        ... 134 more
```

My annotated API endpoint method is `com.example.resource.TowerResource.ascend`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Transactional` interceptor priority is defined by specification to be `Priority.PLATFORM_BEFORE+200`. The fault tolerance interceptor priority is defined by specification to be `Priority.PLATFORM_AFTER+10`. So if the `@Transactional` interceptor fails *after* its `InvocationContext.proceed()`, which is the case when the error happens during commit, then the fault tolerance interceptor is long gone and no retry can possibly happen.

The fault tolerance interceptor priority can be changed by defining a configuration property `mp.fault.tolerance.interceptor.priority`, if there's a need. But by default, what you observe is the intended behavior, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, thanks. I hope changing the priority is not going to have strange side effects, I guess the specification decided of `Priority.PLATFORM_AFTER+10` for a reason.